# HoughLinesP generates an empty image

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, houghlinesp

I'm developing an app which uses OMR (Optical mark recognize) to read bubblesheets, I'm using the OpenCV API but I'm having some troubles with HoughLinesP, when I use it that returns an empty image to me. I used the function of Android, Log.e, to see the **total**, **cols** and **rows** of the image before and after the HoughLinesP.

**My code is a conversion of a C++ code to Java, both uses OpenCV.**

**Before I get the following result:**

> 

**After I get the following result:**

> 

**My code:**

```
private void scanImage(){
    Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread(mediaStorageDir().getPath() + "/" + "test2.jpg", Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    Log.e("[CANAIS]", String.valueOf(img.channels()));

    Size sz = new Size(3,3);
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(img, img, sz, 0);
    Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(img, img, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 75, 10);
    Core.bitwise_not(img, img);

    Mat img2 = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img, img2, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB);

    Mat img3 = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img, img3, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB);

    MatOfInt4 lines = new MatOfInt4();
    
    Log.e("[ORIGINAL IMAGE]", "" + img.total() + "||" + img.rows() + "||" + img.cols());
    
    Imgproc.HoughLinesP(img, lines, 1, Math.PI/180,80,400,10);
    
    Log.e("[LINES IMAGE]", "" + lines.total() + "||" + lines.rows() + "||" + lines.cols());
    
    for(int i = 0; i < lines.total(); i++){
        Mat l = new Mat();
        l.put(i, 0, lines.get(i, 0));
        Point pr = new Point();
        Point ps = new Point();
        pr.x = Double.valueOf(l.get(0, 0).toString());
        pr.y = Double.valueOf(l.get(1, 0).toString());

        ps.x = Double.valueOf(l.get(2, 0).toString());
        ps.y = Double.valueOf(l.get(3,0).toString());

        Scalar scalar = new Scalar(0,0,255);

        Imgproc.line(img2, pr, ps, scalar, 3, Imgproc.LINE_AA, 0);
    }

    showImage(img2);
    MatOfInt4 mt4 = new MatOfInt4(lines);
    LinkedList<Point> corners = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < lines.total(); i++){
        for(int x = i + 1; x <lines.total(); x++){
            MatOfInt4 gen = new MatOfInt4();
            MatOfInt4 gen1 = new MatOfInt4();
            gen1.put(x, 0, mt4.get(x, 0));
            gen.put(i, 0, mt4.get(i, 0));
            Point pt = computeIntersect(gen, gen1);
            if(pt.x >= 0 && pt.y >= 0 && pt.x < img.cols() && pt.y < img.rows()){
                corners.addLast(pt);
            }
        }
    }

    Point center = new Point(0,0);
    MatOfPoint mtp = new MatOfPoint(center);
    for(int i = 0; i < corners.size(); i++){
        center.x += corners.get(i).x;
        center.y += corners.get(i).y;
    }

    center.x *= 1./ corners.size();
    center.y *= 1./ corners.size();

    sortCorners(corners, center);

    Rect r = Imgproc.boundingRect(mtp);
    Log.e("[RECT]", r.toString());

    Mat quad = Mat.zeros(r.height, r.width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
    LinkedList<Point> quad_pts = new LinkedList<>();
    quad_pts.addLast(new Point(0,0));
    quad_pts.addLast(new Point(quad.cols(),0));
    quad_pts.addLast(new Point(quad.cols(),quad.rows()));
    quad_pts.addLast(new Point(0,quad.rows()));

    Mat transmtx = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(corners), Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(quad_pts));
    Imgproc.warpPerspective(img3, quad, transmtx, quad.size());

    showImage(quad);

    Mat cimg = new Mat();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(quad, cimg, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Mat circles = new Mat();
    Imgproc.HoughCircles(cimg, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, img.rows()/8, 100, 75, 0,0);
    for(int i=0; i < circles.total(); i++){
        Point center1 = new Point(Math.round(Double.valueOf(circles.get(i, 0).toString())), Math.round(Double.valueOf(circles.get(i, 1).toString())));
        Imgproc.circle(quad, center1, 3, new Scalar(0,255,0), -1,8,0);
    }

    double averR = 0;
    LinkedList<Double> row = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<Double> col = new LinkedList<>();

    for(int i=0; i < circles.total(); i++){
        boolean found = false;
        String rr = String.valueOf(Math.round(Double.valueOf(circles.get(i, 2).toString())));
        int rrr = Integer.valueOf(rr);
        averR += rrr;

        String x = String.valueOf(Math.round(Double.valueOf(circles.get(i, 0).toString())));
        String y = String.valueOf(Math.round(Double.valueOf(circles.get(i, 1).toString())));

        int xx = Integer.valueOf(x);
        int yy = Integer.valueOf(y);

        for(int j=0; j < row.size(); j++){
            double y2 = row.get(j);
            if(yy - rrr < y2 && yy + rrr > y2){
                found =  true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found){
            row.addLast(Double.valueOf(yy));
        }
        found = false;
        for(int j=0; j < col.size(); j++){
            double x2 = col.get(j);
            if(xx - rrr < x2 && xx + rrr > x2){
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!found){
            col.addLast(Double.valueOf(xx));
        }
    }

    averR /= circles.total();

    Collections.sort(row, new Comparator<Double>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Double o1, Double o2) {
            return Collator.getInstance().compare(o1, o2);
        }
    });
    Collections.sort(col, new Comparator<Double>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Double o1, Double o2) {
            return Collator.getInstance().compare(o1, o2);
        }
    });

    for(int i=0;i<row.size();i++){
        double max = 0;
        double y = row.get(i);
        int ind = -1;
        for(int j=0;j<col.size();j++){
            double x = col.get(i);
            Point c = new Point(x,y);

            //Use an actual circle if it exists
            for(int k=0;k<circles.total();k++){
                double x2 = Double.valueOf(circles.get(k, 0).toString());
                double y2 = Double.valueOf(circles.get(k, 1).toString());
                if(abs(y2-y)<averR && abs(x2-x)<averR){
                    x = x2;
                    y = y2;
                }
            }

            // circle outline
            Imgproc.circle( quad, c, Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(averR)), new Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );
            Rect rect = new Rect(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(x-averR)),Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(y-averR)),Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(2*averR)),Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(2*averR)));
            Mat submat = cimg.adjustROI(rect.width, rect.width, rect.height, rect.height);
            double p =(double)countNonZero(submat)/(submat.size().width*submat.size().height);
            if(p>=0.3 && p>max){
                max = p;
                ind = j;
            }
        }
        if(ind==-1)
            Log.e("[N SEI]", "" + i+1);
        else
            Log.e("[NSEI]", "" + i+1 + "A" + ind);
    }

}
private Point computeIntersect(MatOfInt4 a, MatOfInt4 b){
    Point generc = new Point();
    generc.x = -1;
    generc.y = -1;

    int x1 = Integer.valueOf(a.get(0,0).toString());
    int y1 = Integer.valueOf(a.get(0,1).toString());
    int x2 = Integer.valueOf(a.get(0,2).toString());
    int y2 = Integer.valueOf(a.get(0,3).toString());

    int x3 = Integer.valueOf(b.get(0,0).toString());
    int y3 = Integer.valueOf(b.get(0,1).toString());
    int x4 = Integer.valueOf(b.get(0,2).toString());
    int y4 = Integer.valueOf(b.get(0,3).toString());

    float d = 0;

    if(d == ((float)(x1 - x2) * (y3-y4)) - ((y1-y2) * (x3-x4))){
        Point pt = new Point();
        pt.x = ((x1*y2 - y1*x2) * (x3-x4) - (x1-x2) * (x3*y4 - y3*x4)) / d;
        pt.y = ((x1*y2 - y1*x2) * (y3-y4) - (y1-y2) * (x3*y4 - y3*x4)) / d;
        return pt;
    }
    else
        return generc;
}
private void sortCorners(LinkedList<Point> corners, Point center){
    LinkedList<Point> top = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<Point> bot = new LinkedList<>();

    Log.e("[CORNERS SIZE]", String.valueOf(corners.size()));

    for(int i = 0; i < corners.size(); i++){
        if(corners.get(i).y < center.y)
            top.addLast(corners.get(i));
        else
            bot.addLast(corners.get(i));
    }

    Collections.sort(top, new Comparator<Point>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Point o1, Point o2) {
            return Collator.getInstance().compare(o1, o2);
        }
    });
    Collections.sort(bot, new Comparator<Point>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Point o1, Point o2) {
            return Collator.getInstance().compare(o1, o2);
        }
    });

    Log.e("[TOP SIZE]", String.valueOf(top.size()));

    Point t1 = top.get(0);
    Point tr = top.get(top.size() - 1);
    Point b1 = bot.get(0);
    Point br = bot.get(bot.size() - 1);
    corners.clear();
    corners.addLast(t1);
    corners.addLast(tr);
    corners.addLast(br);
    corners.addLast(b1);
}
```

**The C++ code:**

```
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

//g++ main.cpp -o main -I /usr/local/include/opencv -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


cv::Point2f computeIntersect(cv::Vec4i a, cv::Vec4i b)
{
    int x1 = a[0], y1 = a[1], x2 = a[2], y2 = a[3];
    int x3 = b[0], y3 = b[1], x4 = b[2], y4 = b[3];

    if (float d = ((float)(x1-x2) * (y3-y4)) - ((y1-y2) * (x3-x4)))
    {
        cv::Point2f pt;
        pt.x = ((x1*y2 - y1*x2) * (x3-x4) - (x1-x2) * (x3*y4 - y3*x4)) / d;
        pt.y = ((x1*y2 - y1*x2) * (y3-y4) - (y1-y2) * (x3*y4 - y3*x4)) / d;
        return pt;
    }
    else
        return cv::Point2f(-1, -1);
}

bool comparator2(double a,double b){  
  return a<b;  
 }  
 bool comparator3(Vec3f a,Vec3f b){  
  return a[0]<b[0];  
 }  

bool comparator(Point2f a,Point2f b){  
  return a.x<b.x;  
  }  
 void sortCorners(std::vector<cv::Point2f>& corners, cv::Point2f center)  
 {  


   std::vector<cv::Point2f> top, bot;  
   for (int i = 0; i < corners.size(); i++)  
   {  
     if (corners[i].y < center.y)  
       top.push_back(corners[i]);  
     else  
       bot.push_back(corners[i]);  
   }  


  sort(top.begin(),top.end(),comparator);  
  sort(bot.begin(),bot.end(),comparator); 

   cv::Point2f tl = top[0];  
   cv::Point2f tr = top[top.size()-1];  
   cv::Point2f bl = bot[0];  
   cv::Point2f br = bot[bot.size()-1]; 
   corners.clear();  
   corners.push_back(tl);  
   corners.push_back(tr);  
   corners.push_back(br);  
   corners.push_back(bl);  
 }  


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  Mat img = imread("example.jpg",0);

  cv::Size size(3,3);  
  cv::GaussianBlur(img,img,size,0);  
  adaptiveThreshold(img, img,255,CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY,75,10);  
  cv::bitwise_not(img, img);    

  cv::Mat img2;  
  cvtColor(img,img2, CV_GRAY2RGB);  

  cv::Mat img3;  
  cvtColor(img,img3, CV_GRAY2RGB); 

  vector<Vec4i> lines;  
  HoughLinesP(img, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 80, 400, 10);  
  for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )  
  {  
   Vec4i l = lines[i];  
   line( img2, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);   
  }  

  imshow("example",img2);

  std::vector<cv::Point2f> corners;
  for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
  {
      for (int j = i+1; j < lines.size(); j++)
      {
          cv::Point2f pt = computeIntersect(lines[i], lines[j]);
          if (pt.x >= 0 && pt.y >= 0 && pt.x < img.cols && pt.y < img.rows)
              corners.push_back(pt);
      }
  }

   // Get mass center  
  cv::Point2f center(0,0);  
  for (int i = 0; i < corners.size(); i++)  
  center += corners[i];  
  center *= (1. / corners.size()); 

  sortCorners(corners, center); 

  Rect r = boundingRect(corners); 
  cout<<r<<endl;
  cv::Mat quad = cv::Mat::zeros(r.height, r.width, CV_8UC3);  
  // Corners of the destination image  
  std::vector<cv::Point2f> quad_pts;  
  quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, 0));  
  quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(quad.cols, 0));  
  quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(quad.cols, quad.rows));  
  quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, quad.rows));  

  // Get transformation matrix  
  cv::Mat transmtx = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(corners, quad_pts);  
  // Apply perspective transformation  
  cv::warpPerspective(img3, quad, transmtx, quad.size());  

  imshow("example2",quad);

  Mat cimg;
  
  cvtColor(quad,cimg, CV_BGR2GRAY);
  vector<Vec3f> circles;  
  HoughCircles(cimg, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, img.rows/8, 100, 75, 0, 0 );  
  for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ ){  
    Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
    // circle center  
    circle( quad, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
  }

  imshow("example4",quad);
  waitKey();

  double averR = 0;
  vector<double> row;
  vector<double> col;

  //Find rows and columns of circles for interpolation
  for(int i=0;i<circles.size();i++){  
    bool found = false;  
    int r = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
    averR += r;
    int x = cvRound(circles[i][0]);  
    int y = cvRound(circles[i][1]);
    for(int j=0;j<row.size();j++){
      double y2 = row[j];
      if(y - r < y2 && y + r > y2){
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(!found){
      row.push_back(y);
    }
    found = false;
    for(int j=0;j<col.size();j++){
      double x2 = col[j];
      if(x - r < x2 && x + r > x2){
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(!found){  
      col.push_back(x);
    }
  }

  averR /= circles.size();

  sort(row.begin(),row.end(),comparator2);
  sort(col.begin(),col.end(),comparator2);

  for(int i=0;i<row.size();i++){
    double max = 0;  
    double y = row[i];
    int ind = -1;
    for(int j=0;j<col.size();j++){
      double x = col[j];
      Point c(x,y);  

      //Use an actual circle if it exists
      for(int k=0;k<circles.size();k++){
        double x2 = circles[k][0];
        double y2 = circles[k][1];
        if(abs(y2-y)<averR && abs(x2-x)<averR){
          x = x2;
          y = y2;
        }
      }

      // circle outline  
      circle( quad, c, averR, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );  
      Rect rect(x-averR,y-averR,2*averR,2*averR);  
      Mat submat = cimg(rect);  
      double p =(double)countNonZero(submat)/(submat.size().width*submat.size().height);  
      if(p>=0.3 && p>max){  
        max = p;  
        ind = j;  
      }  
    }
    if(ind==-1)printf("%d:-",i+1);  
    else printf("%d:%c",i+1,'A'+ind);  
    cout<<endl;  
  }  

  // circle outline*/  
  imshow("example3",quad);
  waitKey();
  return 0;
}
```

**When I run the app, I get the following error at this line:**

> sortCorners(corners, center);

**Error:**

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

If anyone could tell me where is the error and how I could arrange it, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run the Canny edge detector to convert the gray image to a binary image before running it through the HoughLinesP transform.

From the HoughLinesP documentation.

"Finds line segments in a **binary** image using the probabilistic Hough transform."